# Pushing Views in array with setTimeout in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to push some views into an array so it shows after a delay.

This was working before but it took some time to load the screen:

incomeData contains some data and incomeView is the array which I render later.

```
incomeData.map((income) => {
    incomeView.push(
        <View key={income.amount} >
        <Text>Test</Text>
        </View>);
});
```

I was showing this like this:

```
render(){
    return(<View>
            {incomeView}
        </View>)
};
```

But then I added setTimeout to add a delay in loading of data now it wont show data.

```
     setTimeout(() => {

    incomeData.map((income) => {
        incomeView.push(
            <View key={income.amount} >
            <Text>Test</Text>
            </View>);
    });

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you can't change data like this after the component has been rendered.

You could use a state change for this:

```
render() {

    var { incomeView } = this.state;

    setTimeout(() => {
      // set the new state here
      this.setState({
        incomeView: newValuesIncomeView
      });
    }, 1000);

   return(<View>
            {incomeView}
        </View>)
}
```